# Question about line integrals and conservative fields

Tags: calculus

Let $\rho : [0,\infty)  \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on $(0 , \infty)$. $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector field. How can I show that

if $f(x) = x \rho(\|x\|) $, then  for every $i \neq j $, we have $$ \frac{ \partial f_i}{\partial x_j } = \frac{ \partial f_j}{\partial x_i} $$ on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \} $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f_i(x)=x_i\rho\left(\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2}\right)$$
$$\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}=\frac{x_ix_j\rho'\left(\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2}}=\frac{x_ix_j\rho'\left(||x||\right)}{||x||}$$

Comment: But, $\rho'$ is with respect to $||x||$? correct? Also, I computed $\frac{ \partial f_j}{\partial x_i} $ and is not equal to your answer. :S

Comment: $\rho'$ is the derivative of $\rho$ evaluated at $||x||$

Comment: the derivative with respect to $x_j$ ?

Comment: If you want, yes is a derivative with respect to $||x||$